# Speech Recognition RecognizeAsync on keydown

Tags: c#

Im trying to have my program listen to me only when i press the shift key so called Push to talk and i tried to use the following code but when the key is pressed for longer then 1-2 seconds i get the following error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
Additional information: Cannot perform this operation while the recognizer is doing recognition.**

Here is part of the code:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            label1.Text = "Speak";
            RecEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            label1.Text = "Ready";
            RecEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Form1_KeyDown` function is called repetitively while the button is pressed.

You need to check whether the button has already been pressed

```
    private bool recognitionRunning;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey && !recognitionRunning)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            label1.Text = "Speak";
            RecEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

            recognitionRunning = true;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            label1.Text = "Ready";
            RecEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

            recognitionRunning = false;
        }
    }
```